# Bash script condition always passing even when grep should return nothing

Tags: bash, scripting, grep, exif

I am having issues when trying to return the one image file that fits the parameters. $1 is the search parameter, in this incident it is "real" which is a tag on one of the images (not two) in the given folder. What happens when I call it "./test.sh real" is it prints off both images, rather than just the one. I imagine it has to deal with me setting up the function return as a variable and/or my condition statement, but I am not quite sure.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in specim/*.jpg
do
    image=$(exiftool -EXIF:XPKeywords $f | grep "$1")
    if [[ !  -z  "$image// }"  ]]; then
    echo $f
fi
```

what's returned:

```
../../test.sh real
specim/image2.jpg
specim/image.jpg
```

This bash script prints off what I want, only the one image rather than both (as the exiftool stuff which I don't want, but this was just a test):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.jpg
do
    exiftool -EXIF:XPKeywords $f | grep $1
done
```

result:

```
./test2.sh real
XP Keywords                     : name;real
```

any help would be appreciated and it's probably super simple...
Thanks

Comment: `"$image// }"` looks like a typo for `"${image// }"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably as you suspected, just a minor change to fix, try instead:

```
if [[ !  -z  "$image"  ]]; then
```

### Explanation

Let's say when there is a match by exiftool and grep, then your `$image` variable contains this:

```
abcabcabc
```

But when there is no output, `$image` contains: (nothing)

In your test condition, you had:

```
if [[ !  -z  "$image// }"  ]]; then
```

So, in the first case bash sees this:

```
if [[ !  -z  "abcabcabc// }"  ]]; then
```

But in the second case, bash sees this:

```
if [[ !  -z  "// }"  ]]; then
```

The test is saying `if "// }" is NOT zero-value, then...` however `"// }"` is always going to be not zero value, it is something, it is a string consisting of two slashes a space and a curly brace. So since there is something there, something not zero-value, that is why the `then` part is triggered even when you have no matches in `$image`. So by removing this `// }` it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Another option might be:

```
if [[ -n "$image" ]]; then
```

to check whether only the `$image` variable contains something, rather than `! -z ...`

Answer (score 3):

You are running `exiftool` and `grep` (+ a test and echo) for each `.jpg` in that directory...  not very efficient...
`exiftool` can do all that by itself via the `-if EXPR` option, e.g.

```
exiftool -q -s3 -if '$tag=~/pattern/' -filename ./*.jpg
```

(here combined with `-q` - quiet and `-s[NUM]` - short output format: print values only, see the manual for more details)
So, in your particular case the whole script could be replaced by:

```
exiftool -q -s3 -if \$Exif:XPKeywords=~/"$1"/ -filename specim/*.jpg
```

e.g. running the `test.sh` script with four test files that have the following `XPKeywords` values:

```
exiftool -Exif:XPKeywords specim/*.jpg
======== specim/1.jpg
XP Keywords                     : xname;real
======== specim/2.jpg
XP Keywords                     : yname;different
======== specim/3.jpg
XP Keywords                     : wname;true
======== specim/4.jpg
XP Keywords                     : wname;unreal
    4 image files read
```

running `test.sh real` returns:

```
1.jpg
4.jpg
```

and `test.sh unreal` returns:

```
4.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep`'s exit status is whether or not it matched something, so why capture grep's output and then test it, as a string, for emptiness? You could do

```
if exiftool -EXIF:XPKeywords $f | grep -q "$1" ; then
    echo $f
fi
```

if you wanted.